# How to connecting signalR to react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, signalr

I trying to connect with SignalR. After request, does not return response.
LIBRARY: react-native-signalr

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native';
import signalr from 'react-native-signalr';
import store from '../../../../init/store';

export class SignalR extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        //This is the server under /example/server published on azure.
        const connection = signalr.hubConnection('https://test.get-bagel.com:8000', {
            qs: { bearer: store.getState().auth.token.split(' ')[1] }
        });
        connection.logging = true;

        const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('notifications');
        //receives broadcast messages from a hub function, called "helloApp"
        proxy.on('endUpdateContact', (argOne, argTwo, argThree, argFour) => {
            console.log('message-from-server', argOne, argTwo, argThree, argFour);
            //Here I could response by calling something else on the server...
        });
        
        connection.start({
            pingInterval: null,
            transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents']
        }).done(() => {
            console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);

            proxy.invoke("endUpdateContact", 'endUpdateContact')
                .done((directResponse) => {
                    console.log('direct-response-from-server', directResponse);
                }).fail(() => {
                    console.warn('Something went wrong when calling server, it might not be up and running?')
                });

        }).fail(() => {
            console.log('Failed');
        });

        //connection-handling
        connection.connectionSlow(() => {
            console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
        });

        connection.error((error) => {
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            let detailedError = '';
            if (error.source && error.source._response) {
                detailedError = error.source._response;
            }
            if (detailedError === 'An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.') {
                console.log('When using react-native-signalr on ios with http remember to enable http in App Transport Security https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr/issues/14')
            }
            console.debug('SignalR error: ' + errorMessage, detailedError)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});
```

Logs:

> [13:21:14 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notifications'.
> DEBUG  [13:21:14 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Negotiating with
> 'https://test.get-bagel.com:8000/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&bearer=eyJ0e...'
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:15 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: webSockets transport
> starting.
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:15 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Connecting to websocket
> endpoint
> 'wss://test.get-bagel.com:8000/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&bearer=eyJ0eXAiOi...'.
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Websocket opened.
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: webSockets transport
> connected. Initiating start request.
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: The start request
> succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive
> with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of
> 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
>
> LOG  Now connected, connection ID=ca21c32a-cfc4-4479-9cce-********
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR: Invoking
> notifications.endUpdateContact
>
> DEBUG  [13:21:18 GMT+0300 (EEST)] SignalR:
> notifications.endUpdateContact failed to execute.   Error:
> 'endUpdateContact' method could not be resolved. No method found with
> that name.
>
> WARN  Something went wrong when calling server, it might not be up
> and running?

**//Now I can send request, but i doesn't get response**